# Why's power pivot measure area grayed out?

Tags: microsoft-excel, powerpivot

Can some one please help me? I am a new user of Microsoft power pivot and while I was working on my data, I realized the measured section is all grayed out and I cant enter formulas there. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks for your help.

Mawriz

Answer (score 0):

Active cell in sheet must be in the pivot table area.